# Minimal package using electron-builder

Tags: electron-builder

I have a web app built using NextJS. My goal is to create an Electron app that serves that web app remotely using `BrowserView`. I don't want the Electron app to have any local assets inside, like .js bundles.

I have `main.js` and `preload.js` defined, and in dev mode (which I run using `electron .`) the app works just fine.

I'm using `electron-builder` to build the app. I have the config defined in `package.json`.

```
  "main": "electron/main.js",
  "build": {
    "appId": "appid",
    "productName": "ProductName",
    "copyright": "Copyright @ 2019",
    "mac": {
      "category": "public.app-category.business"
    },
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "electronBuildResources",
      "output": "electron-dist"
    }
  },
```

First, it fails due to this error `Error: Unresolved node modules: worker-loader, webpack-cli`. But I don't need to build any local assets for the app, why do I need Webpack here? I don't even have Webpack as my dependency because NextJS handles all the building internally.

I can skip the error using `ELECTRON_BUILDER_ALLOW_UNRESOLVED_DEPENDENCIES=true`. However, when it continues, it rebuilds some of my node_modules, and I don't need that. My `main.js` and `preload.js` has only `require("electron")` inside, and no other deps. In the final build directory I also have the `node_modules` directory with some of the packages. But I don't need them as well.

The question is, how do I pack just `main.js` and `preload.js` into an minimal Electron application, without touching my web app node_modules at all?